# Ethereum deployed contract not defined in Geth Javascript console

Tags: ethereum, truffle, geth

I cannot access a deployed and mined Ethereum contract on a private network from the Geth Javascript console. Not sure where the issue is, any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time.

**Scenario**

I launched my Geth as below

```
geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/myProject --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcport 8546 --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --unlock 0 console
```

I've deployed and mined an Ethereum contract (to simplify things, I've used the default MetaCoin contract provided by Truffle), and I got the trx and contract address back. 
I can access it from the Truffle console but if I try from the Geth Javascript console I get an error.

Please refer to the pictures below:

[Truffle console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V9Ba.png)

[Geth javascript console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui4la.png)

**Software used**

- Geth (v1.7.3-stable)
- NodeJS (v6.12.3)
- TestRPC (v6.0.3 (ganache-core:2.0.2))
- Truffle (v4.0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geth does not know about `MetaCoin`. In Geth console, you need to do:

```
var MetaCoin = web3.eth.Contract(metaCoinJsonAbi, itsAddress);
// or web3.eth.contract depending on the version of Web3
```

Then you can use it. [Refer to this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#web3-eth-contract).